# Do bosses scale to your level in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls

Do bosses in Dark Souls scale to your level?

For example, fighting a certain boss at level 20 would be the same difficulty as fighting that same boss at level 50.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, nothing scales to your level in Dark Souls.

For example, you can see the stats for the Taurus Demon [here](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/taurus-demon). It's HP is fixed - ie. not related to your own level.

Enemies do become stronger in New Game+ and beyond, but the increase in strength is not related to the player's level.

Comment: Enemies will probably increase in stats/difficulty in New Game+ and subsequent playthroughs though.

Comment: Both answer and comment are correct. Enemies do not scale with soul level but they do become stronger with every subsequent new game + reached with the same character.

Comment: What does "in New Game+" mean?

Comment: @Dronz: New Game+ is a general gaming concept that many games, particularly JRPGs, implement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Game_Plus. In Dark Souls, each new game+ playthrough becomes more difficult.

Comment: Dark Souls NG+ differences: http://darksouls.wikidot.com/new-game-plus

Answer (score -5):

They scale. Dont level up, just get better equipment and bosses will be butter

Comment: This is a direct contradiction to the accepted answer. Do you have any sources for your claim?

Comment: This is completely false.

Comment: If your stats are high, you pretty much one-shot everything in the first area.